# Ordinary Differential Equations ODEs Solve the Initial Value Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the initial Value problem and explain please

[image]

Please help

Comment: a. that's the second part of differential equations that I haven't learned yet, but I will in the upcoming fall semester.
b. what have you attempted so far?

Comment: not sure where to start

Comment: @user146167 If you're done with this question and if you think any of answers so far is good enough, I suggest you accept an answer. If you still need help, consider updating the question or commenting on the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint 1:** For a constant matrix $M$,
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}e^{tM}=Me^{tM}
$$
**Hint 2:**
$$
\left[\begin{array}{rr}-1&-4\\1&-1\end{array}\right]
=\left[\begin{array}{rr}-2i&2i\\1&1\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{cc}-1-2i&0\\0&-1+2i\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{rr}-2i&2i\\1&1\end{array}\right]^{-1}
$$

Comment: What would I need to do first?

Comment: @user146167: try $M=\left(\begin{array}{rr}-1&-4\\1&-1\end{array}\right)$.

Comment: so would i need to find the eigen values first?

Comment: @user146167: whatever your favorite way to compute $e^{tM}$ is.

Comment: so i  would get lambda = -1+-2i

Comment: $ e^{Mt}=1+Mt+\frac{t^{2}M^{2}}{2}+\frac{t^{3}M^{3}}{6}+..$

Comment: @JoseGarcia: it's usually easier to use the Jordan Decomposition that I provided in Hint 2.